# How to add content limit in custom grid column in magento 2.is anyone have any idea

Tags: magento2

How to add content limit in custom grid column in magento 2.is anyone have any idea..ie nothing string limit in column
i found below like this we can do it in magento 1

```
$this->addColumnAfter('addons', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Addons'),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,            
            'index' => 'addons',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'string_limit'  => '500', /* added for content limit */

        ), 'billing_name');
```

[image]

Comment: Grid is UI component or form field.?

Answer (score 0):

According to below code you can use string_limit in Magento2 like as you are using in Magento1 with Render

```
namespace Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer;

/**
 * Backend Grid Renderer
 */
class Longtext extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    /**
     * Render contents as a long text
     *
     * Text will be truncated as specified in string_limit, truncate or 250 by default
     * Also it can be html-escaped and nl2br()
     *
     * @param \Magento\Object $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Object $row)
    {
        $truncateLength = 250;
        // stringLength() is for legacy purposes
        if ($this->getColumn()->getStringLimit()) {
            $truncateLength = $this->getColumn()->getStringLimit();
        }
        if ($this->getColumn()->getTruncate()) {
            $truncateLength = $this->getColumn()->getTruncate();
        }
        $text = $this->filterManager->truncate(parent::_getValue($row), array('length' => $truncateLength));
        if ($this->getColumn()->getEscape()) {
            $text = $this->escapeHtml($text);
        }
        if ($this->getColumn()->getNl2br()) {
            $text = nl2br($text);
        }
        return $text;
    }
}
```